# exporting 10.2 .esriaddin to 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, vb

I have successfully exported .esriaddin I created in 10.2 Arcobjects SDK to 10.0. The installation succeeded but the problem I am having is that whenever I use the command `me.Close()` to close the form Arcmap 10.0 crashes when i press the button. I have inserted that code in the OnClick method of a button on the form. However the same esriaddin works fine in 10.2 and `me.close()` has no problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: a) see @jon_two answer b) do you have a try/catch in the button OnClick method that handles the exception and doesn't rethrow? Make sure it's a messagebox or log or something.

Comment: i used the following code: `Try
   Me.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
   Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addins are not backwards compatible and cannot be installed on an earlier version of ArcMap.

You'll have to set up a development machine or VM with ArcGIS 10.0 and Visual Studio 2010 to compile the addin then it can be distributed to PCs running later versions of ArcGIS.

Comment: 10.0 is also retired: http://downloads.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/arcgis_desktop/ArcGIS_PLC.pdf

Comment: @JayCummins ha, tell that to our clients! :-)

Comment: I hear you!  I have 10.0 client myself!  Thankfully, just 1!

Comment: you are right, but I am only able to get hold of 10.2 on the VM. Thought it would be ok if I compiled the addin in 3.5 framework and change the Target in the xml file to 10.0. [link]http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46724/is-it-possible-to-target-an-arcmap-add-in-to-an-earlier-version

Comment: @Daz I hadn't seen that post before - didn't know you could do that! I imagine you'd still run into problems if your addin uses parts of the API that didn't exist at 10.0 though.