# Can I compile an addin developed in ArcGIS 10.3.1 for use with 10.1 and 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, add-in

I made an update to one of my addins mainly because users requested new features. I made the changes and compiled the addin in 10.3.1. Although I specified that the addin is compatible with 10.3 and higher I am getting emails from users wondering if I could make it work for 10.2.

ESRI provides a way to save Map Documents for downward compatibility.  Is there a way to compile an addin developed in ArcGIS 10.3 for use with legacy versions (10.1, 10.2)

Note: my ArcObject references are set to non specific version (Specific Version = False)

Answer (score 2):

You can compile it for lowest supported version. As long as you aren't using features that were added in a later version it will be forward compatible.

So in your case build it for 10.2. Be sure to test that things work as expected in each version to be supported since various bug fixes, etc between version can cause issues in your Add-in.

Also see here:
[Is it possible to target an ArcMap add-in to an earlier version?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46724/is-it-possible-to-target-an-arcmap-add-in-to-an-earlier-version)