# Arcmap 10.3 addin is not working on 10.2.1

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, add-in

I have made an add-in using Visual Studio 2013 and ArcObjects 10.3 .Net SDK. It is running fine on 10.3. I want to run this on 10.2.1.  I have change the following settings:

```
<Targets>
<Target name="Desktop" version="10.2" />
</Targets>
```

It is installed but when I click on it ArcMap crashes without any error. I have tried on two different systems also. I have also tried by creating a blank form on button click to check but it didn't work and crashes.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format

Comment: You need to use the 10.2 SDK to write add-ins for 10.2

Comment: so i have to configure my all development from 10.3 to 10.2?I cannot install 10.2 sdk with arcgis 10.3

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46724/is-it-possible-to-target-an-arcmap-add-in-to-an-earlier-version and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177730/can-i-compile-an-addin-developed-in-arcgis-10-3-1-for-use-with-10-1-and-10-2

Comment: It's to do with the dependent libraries, you can go forward but not back. This is why I'm using the oldest version of ArcGis in the office to develop tools. You need to compile the addin on the minimum version you want it to run on and then it will be compatible with later versions i.e. a 10.2 tool will work on 10.3 but not the other way around.